# Change color and names of terminals in VScode with a script

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a big fan of personalizing my terminals in vscode, I like having them set up like this:

[image]

The problem with this, however, is that I often need to restart my vscode instance, or log out from ssh etc.
When I do that, my terminals reset.

Is there some way for me to open new terminals through a script?
i.e. something like this, so that I could write a script for it.

`code --terminal --color=blue --name=docker --command=docker exec -it 7935b bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the [Terminals Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-terminals) extension using a JSON file:

[image: terminal manager]

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted, thanks!